# UITableViewCell and UITableView (did select a row) navigation to otherViewcontroller

Tags: iphone

I hav a `UITableViewCell` and `UITableView` in a single view.Clicking on particular row of `UITableView` ,It navigates to anotherViewController.But I am not able to navigate to otherViewController on clicking `UITableViewCell`.How can i do this??

For `UITableView` I am using this code:

```
-(void)pushView1:(id)sender{
    if(edController == nil)
    edController = [[EditableDetailCell alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditableDetailCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:edController animated:YES];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITableViewCell *tbcel;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    tbcel.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    tbcel.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    tbcel.text = aBook.Name;
    switch(indexPath.section)
    {
         case 0:
            cell.text = aBook.Address;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.text = aBook.Phone;
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.text = aBook.Purchase;
    }
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(edController == nil)
    edController = [[EditableDetailCell alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditableDetailCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:edController animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

What should I do for UITableViewCell??

[image: ist is tableviewcell and below it in block is tableview]

Comment: UITableViewCell are part of table view right? Then why do you want to have an action for it seperately

Comment: Its a UiTableViewCell not included in Tableview it is inserted in View Through interface builder library separately.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's from IB or anything. UITableViewCell isn't for this purpose. See my answer below.

Comment: This freak puppet is scarying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

what you want to push is not a UITableViewCell

It's another View.

You can say

```
YourCustomView *view = [[YourCustomView alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:Yes];
```

but I never see any code passing to another cell.

A cell is used to customize the look of you UITableView.

Add:

I think the if statement is not useful here.

Do you mean

```
if(edController == nil){
    edController = [[EditableDetailCell alloc] initWithnibName:@"EditableDetailCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:edController animated:YES];
}
```

or an empty view is going to be passed any way.

Comment: I am trying pushview1 method here for tableviewcell(customer 2) to navigate it but not navigating with this method

Comment: Did you make it an IBAction and connect this method with the correct button in the Interface Builder? That customer2 beside the picture is a button right?

Comment: customer 2 is text in UITableViewcell

Comment: i am using void  not IBAction in method and callling it through  [tbcel addTarget:self action:@selector(pushView1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: what i need that when i click on my custom cell having text "customer 2" (that i have added from library separately) a new view should be pushed/appeared upon tapping it.

Comment: everything is solved out in different way! I have added a custom button on my custom cell and connect its iboutlet to method "PushView1" . now its pushing or appearing a view upon tapping it!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    NSLog(“Selected Row %d”, indexPath.row);
    YourNextViewController *objVC = (YourNextViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerIdentifier"];
   [self presentViewController: objVC animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```