# Push new view on clicking Table Cell, How's that possible ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview

I want to push a new view when the user select a cell on tableview, How it is possible ?

and that selected cell data i wanna to print on the new view ? give it to code me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override this delegate methode of UItableViewDelegate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Value Selected by user
      NSString *selectedValue = [displayValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//Initialize new viewController
      NewViewController *viewController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
//Pass selected value to a property declared in NewViewController
      viewController.valueToPrint = selectedValue;
//Push new view to navigationController stack
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

See this links for more info 
1) [Table view tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/)
2) [StackOverflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564795/uitableviewcell-and-uitableview-did-select-a-row-navigation-to-otherviewcontro)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UINavigationController` and call `pushViewController:` in the `didSelectRowAtIndePath:` method.

To display the information, I'd create a new `UIViewController`, and create some properties which you can set to use for displaying the information.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement a code in  the method '(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath '. When you select cell in table, this method will be called. That's why you have to implement what you want.

I hope the following code will be helpful to you.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



                    if (!yourObject) {
                    yourObject = [[yourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourViewController" bundle:nil];

                }

                UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
                self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
                [backBarButtonItem release];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourObject animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you can create the Object of the class and you can 
user:`NavigationController` Or `presentModleViewController` to go another view.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourClassobject animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self presentModalViewController:yourClassobject animated:YES];
```